# What file metadata is preserved by Git?

Tags: git, metadata

What file metadata is preserved by Git?

What are from ACL, owner, group ID, file permissions, atime, ctime, mtime preserved in Git history?

As I know executable permission is treated specially:

```
git add --chmod=+x one.txt
git add --chmod=-x two.txt
```

Is anything else preserved by Git?

Comment: It wouldn't really make sense to store stuff like owners, group IDs, etc. as those users/groups may not (indeed, *probably* won't) be present on the other computers.

Comment: @ceejayoz What about `ctime` and `mtime`? They can be meaningful.

Comment: I'd say they're not really meaningful when you've got `git blame` and `git log` available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/ContentLimitations

> By design, git cannot track other aspects of the filesystem, including:
>
> - File modes (**except for the "executable" bit, and being symbolic link**)
> - File ownership (commits, however, remember 'author' and 'committer' info)
> - File modification and access times (these are set to **checkout time** for files which are modified during checkout)
> - File ACLs and extended attributes
> - Hard links
> - Empty directories (although it is not a fundamental limitation, git just automatically removes empty directories and does not add empty directories)

Comment: Thanks for this link! I suspected that `xattrs` were lost during `git` transfers (push, clone,etc), but wanted a definitive reference.

Answer (score 11):

Only executable bit. Git [concentrates](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Git_FAQ#Does_Git_track_all_file_data_and_metadata.3F) on storing file content.

If you need to preserve something else you have to to do it yourself or use some kind of metadata helpers like [metastore](https://github.com/przemoc/metastore) or [gibak](https://github.com/mfp/gibak).

Answer (score 11):

Virtually none.

Git will look at the `x` bits in the result of `stat`.  If any of the three are set, Git will save the file using a tree entry in which the `mode` is `100755`.  Otherwise Git will save the file using a tree entry in which the `mode` is `100644`.

This does not depend on any of the other mode bits (except that the file must be a file, not a directory—Git does not save directories—nor a symbolic link).  A file whose actual mode is `100` (`--x------`) is saved as `100755`.