# Tracking file permissions in Git

Tags: git

This is the actual situation:
I create a new repository with just one file. I make this file read-only (chmod 444) and want to commit that. After that i make a bare repository of that and do make a clone repository of that somewhere. The file in this new repository has now the permission 644 as usual git behavior.

How do i make git read ALL file permission in the first place?

I already tried to add to config core.fileMode true, but it doesn't work. Hopefully someone can help me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retaining file permissions with Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207728/retaining-file-permissions-with-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What file metadata is preserved by Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45578579/what-file-metadata-is-preserved-by-git)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+preserve+file+permissions

Comment: @Vlad274 you are right.